# How to call controller action from helper?

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, helper

Is it possible to call my controller action from a helper?

I have a controller action in **app\code\local\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\controllers\IndexController.php**

```
public function apiAction()
{
    echo "hello";

}
```

This is a snippet of my helper **app\code\local\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Helper\Data.php**. I try to call the controller action *apiAction()*.

```
public function getIsSubscribedAtNewsletter2Go($email)
{
    $url = '/fekete_newsletter2go/index/api';

    $data = array(
        'email' => $email,
    );

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { return "fail!"; }

    return "success";

}
```

But this always returns "**fail!**".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. My dev site is protected with directory protection...

[image]

...so I had to change it to this:

```
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl() .'/fekete_newsletter2go/index/api';

$data = array(
    'email' => $email,
);

$auth = base64_encode("ourUser:ourPassword");

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => 'Authorization: Basic '. $auth,
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
```